# how to display data in a tabular form from two tables where one row id has two docket no

Tags: php

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
customer(
   id int autoincrement,
   fname varchar,
   lname varchar,
   email varchar,
   phone int,
   address varchar,
   product_id int,
   lead_id int,
   state varchar,
   district varchar,
   date date,
   entered by varchar,
   assign int,
   primary key(id)
);
```

Table 2:

```
docket(
   docket_no int auto_incremet,
   cid,
   primary key(docket_no),
   foreign key(cid)references customer id
);
```

I'm getting the values from a form and saving it to my database when the user clicks the Submit button. I am not taking the value for docket no it s auto increment value for each customer.

There can be two dockets number for a same customer id.

Now I want to display all the customer details in a tabular form including docket no like

> fname | email | phone | address | productid | lead_id | state | district | date | enteredby | assignedto | docket

**My problem:**

How to print those values in the tabular column if there are more than one docket for the same customer?

Comment: Hi, this seems extremely basic. You are probably better off working through a tutorial or book.